# Drush or bash command to turn off default Drupal cron

Tags: drupal, jenkins, cron, drush

Is there any easy way to turn off Drupal cron like setting 'Never' in admin/config/system/cron?
Need to use such command in Jenkins bash script for automatic Drupal instance spin-up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
drush vset cron_safe_threshold 0
```